# How to solve undefined method in PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have this problem where i have to query lots of data as im using has_many :through relationship. this code works in sqlite but not in PostgreSQL

**my Controller:**

```
    @task_logs_unapprove = TaskLog.includes(:client).includes(:staff).where(completed_at: nil).page(params[:page]).per_page(10).all
```

**And my Views:**

```
    <div class="panel panel-dark panel-light-green">
  <div class="panel-heading"><span class="panel-title">Unapprove Task Logs</span>
    <div class="panel-heading-controls"><%= will_paginate @task_logs_unapprove, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %></div>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead class="cf">
      <tr>
        <th>Task Code</th>
        <th>Client</th>
        <th>Staff</th>
        <th>Work Time Today</th>
        <th colspan="4"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @task_logs_unapprove.each do |task_log| %>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Name"><strong><%= task_log.task_code %></strong></td>
        <td data-title="Name"><strong><%= task_log.client_name %></strong></td>
        <td data-title="Name"><strong><%= task_log.staff_name %></strong></td>
        <td data-title="Name"><strong><%= task_log.sum_of_hrs %></strong></td>
        <td data-title="Name"><strong><%= link_to 'View', task_log %></strong></td>
        <td data-title="Name"><strong><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_log_path(task_log) %></strong></td>
        <td data-title="Name"><strong><%= link_to ' Unapproved', complete_task_log_path(task_log), method: :patch %></strong></td>
        <td data-title="Name"><strong><%= link_to 'Delete', task_log, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></strong></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Take note this works in SqlLite but not in PostgreSQL

**heres the error from my logs in heroku:**

```
    ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass):
<div class="panel-heading">
<span class="panel-title">Unapprove Task Logs</span>
<div class="panel-heading-controls">
<%= will_paginate @task_logs_unapprove, renderer: BootstrapPagin  <div class="panel-heading"> <span class="panel-title">Approve Task Logs</span> <div class="panel-heading-controls"><%= will_paginate @task_logs_approve, renderer: BootstrapPaginat  <div class="panel-heading"><span class="panel-title">Unapprove Task Logs</span><div class="panel-heading-controls"><%= will_paginate @task_logs_unapprove, renderer: BootstrapPagin  <div class="panel-heading"> <span class="panel-title">Approve Task Logs</span> <div class="panel-heading-controls"><%= will_paginate @task_logs_approve, renderer: BootstrapPaginat</div>nd %>iv>ong>Sorry!</strong> You Dont Have Permission To View This Page.m_of_hrs %>
</td>
```

the full_name error is a column in my **staff** and **client** table

Comment: This has nothing to do with you using postgres but rather it is the data you have in that database.

Comment: It is hard to tell from the code where the issue lies, as there is not a single reference to `full_name` here. My guess is that `client_name` is defined as `client.full_name`. If so, then one of your task_logs is not assigned with any client.

Comment: i define the `client_name` in my task_log.rb model as like this ```def client_name
     #{client.full_name}
end``` 
same with the staff_name

Answer (score 0):

> i define the client_name in my task_log.rb model as like this def
>   client_name #{client.full_name} end same with the staff_name

I suppose that your model task_log does not have related client, so it's nil